# Find Capacitance between A and B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image: Plz Refer Image]

Will the resistor's affect the capacitance between A and B?

I had no idea about how to solve it as most of these type of question that I have done before are either purely resistors or purely capacitors.
So I tried by short circuiting the resistors and so the point A and B will become the same point and so the capacitance will become zero.

But apparently the answer is 2μF , By seeing the answer I thing that we have to just add the horizontal capacitors in series , but why ?

Where did I went wrong and what should be the approach to such question?

Comment: I am downvoting for lack of efforts by the OP.

Comment: This is a question from our recent test and many of us in the class dint got the answer and i am the only one to post it here and the question is only this much so where is lack of effort ?? i am posting on stack exchange for the first time so where did i go wrong ??

Comment: Maybe you can indicate how you attempted to solve this problem, what was your reasoning behind your apparently incorrect solution?  After all, this site is not so that other people can provide solutions to your problems, but rather that other people can help your solve your problems.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little trick going on in this circuit.

You may recognize this as a version of a Wheatstone bridge - except that the resistors in one arm of the bridge are capacitors.

Now it turns out that this bridge is perfectly balanced - the ratio of the resistors in the top row is 1:2, and the ratio of the capacitors in the bottom is 2:1. This means that at any frequency, there will be no net voltage across the 6 µF capacitor (for a given charge, the voltage across a capacitor is $V=\frac{Q}{C}$ so the larger capacitor has the smaller voltage across it.

Since we can ignore the 6 µF capacitor (which has no voltage across it, so doesn't participate in the circuit), we are left with a circuit with two resistors and two capacitors. And how you can apply your usual rules to determine the effective capacitance.

In the more general case, you would compute the complex impedance of a circuit by writing $Z=\frac{1}{j\omega C}$ for the impedance of a capacitor, and $Z=j\omega L$ for an inductor. Then combine all impedances with the usual rules of parallel and series impedances, and get the "general" result. But for this special case, you don't need to do that.